# React - changing text based on what element is hovered

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a rectangle div box on my page that contains various elements including a Font Awesome download icon.  I want to display a specific text when the user hovers over the entire div, and then I want to change that text when the download button is hovered.  I see the text change/show when the div is hovered, but don't see the text change when the download button is hovered.  I added a console log in the download hover and that does show up.  So I'm guessing the component is not re-rendering to display the updated text.

```js
    const [viewDownloadText, setViewDownloadText] = useState('');
    ...

    return (
        <div
            className={'product d-flex'}
            key={product.id}
            onClick={() => openPDF(product.name)}
            onMouseOver={() => setViewDownloadText('Click to view')}
            onMouseOut={() => setViewDownloadText('')}
        >
            {viewDownloadText && (
                <div className={'click-text'}>{viewDownloadText}</div>
            )}

            <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={'SDS-download'}
                icon={faFileDownload}
                size={'2x'}
                onMouseOver={() => {
                    console.log('download set!');
                    setViewDownloadText('Click to download');
                }}
                onMouseOut={() => {
                    setViewDownloadText('Click to view');
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in the hoover handlers of the download icon?

Comment: That did it!  If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thank you so much!